# SQL query to rank items

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a data set in which I need to rank rows by a score column.  Obvious answer is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select ID, Name, Score, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Score desc) as Rank
from MyTable
order by Score desc
```

but there's a catch.  If two records have the same score, then they must have the same rank, and the record that comes after them must skip back to reflect their natural order, e.g.

```
ID      Name        Score       Rank
---     ----        -----       ----    
13      Fred        47          1   
77      Bob         36          2   
88      Harry       36          2
10      John        23          4
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use rank or dense_rank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

select ID, Name, Score, RANK() over (PARTITION BY Score  ORDER BY Score  DESC) as Rank
from MyTable

Comment: Well... that was simple.  Thanks, and welcome to Stackoverflow, Dhaval!

Comment: For the benefit of future Googlers, see [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: BTW, don't "Partition by Score"; that'll reset the ranks for every new score.